# River flow accumulation: % upstream deforestation area as input

Tags: google-earth-engine, rivers, flow-accumulation

I am trying to create a 'flow accumulation' raster whereby each river pixel tells me the % upstream area that has been deforested.

This screenshot shows the HydroSHEDS Flow Accumulation dataset. I have drawn four circles (ignore big red circle) around four pixels at the start of one river. So each pixel essentially has its own catchment area, with a certain # of 30x30m deforested pixels (blue in this case) inside it. Is this possible in GEE?
[image: Flow Accumulation and deforestation pixels]

Comment: I've not used GEE but in any standard GIS system you would use your flow accumulation raster along with your flow direction raster to generate catchment boundaries which you could then use to answer your question.

Comment: The thing is that I do not need to work with sub catchments. I think this is a spatially explicit operation, essentially each pixel needs to get a value with % upstream pixels showing deforestation.